# Multiple grep (with regex's) functions not working in Perl script

Tags: regex, perl

Having trouble with a script right now. 
Trying to filter out portions of a file and put them into a scalar. Here is the code.

```
 @value = (grep {m/(III[ABC])/g and m//g }<$fh>)
 print @value;
 @value = (grep { m/[012]iii/g}(<$fh>));
 print @value;
```

When I run the first `grep` , the values appear in the print statment. But when I run the second `grep`. The 2nd print statement doesnt print anything. Does adding a second grep, cancel out the effectiveness of the first grep ?

I know that first and second grep work because even when I commented out the first grep. The second grep function worked. 
All I really want to do, is filter out information, for multiple different individual arrays. I am really confused as to how to fix this problem, since I am planning on adding more grep's to the script.

Comment: Do you want to add the result of second `grep` to array `@value`?

Comment: The first grep evaluates `<$fh>` in list context, thus exhausing the filehandle. The 2nd grep will find nothing remaining to read from `<$fh>`.  If you want to perform multiple operations on the same lines from `<$fh>` you may either need the `while(<$fh>){...` idiom, or to slurp the file into an array for further processing.

Comment: @red0ct yes, I am still trying to figure out how to append data to array's, with no luck or success.

Comment: @DavidO I have tried using a `while(<$fh>)` loop, and it keeps giving me two results. Either it will give me multiple repeats of the same data (I only need  it once), or some of the regex wont work at all. Also it seems as though `while` loops dont work well with multiple regex's.

Comment: To append data to array you can use the `push` instruction like `push @value, @newarray`. But DavidO is right. There is no data to read in your filehandle after the first grep. Read all data from `$fh` to array like `@data = <$fh>` and then try with push if you want

Comment: @zdim yes `m//g` is in there

Answer (score 4):

The first read on `<$fh>` gets to the end of the file.  Then the second invocation has nothing to read.  Thus if you comment out the first one this doesn't happen and the second one works.

The code below adds to the same array.  Change to the commented out code if needed. The regex is simplified, since it requires a comment while it doesn't affect the actual question.  Please put it back the way it was, if that was what you really meant.

You can either rewind the filehandle after all lines have been read

```
my @vals = grep { /III[ABC]/ } <$fh>;
seek $fh, 0, 0;
# ready for reading again from the beginning
push @vals, grep { /[012]iii/ } <$fh>;
#or:  my @vals_2 = grep { /[012]iii/ } <$fh>;
```

Or you can read all lines into an array that you can *then* process repeatedly.

```
my @original = <$fh>;

my @vals = grep { /III[ABC]/ } @original;
push @vals, grep { m/[012]iii/ } @original; 
# or assign to a different array
```

If you don't need to store these results in such order it would be far more efficient to read the file line by line, and process and add as you go.

---

**Update**

I simplified the originally posted regex in order to focus on the question at hand, since the exact condition inside the block has no bearing on it. See the Note below. Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for bringing it up and for explaining that `//` "*repeats the last successful query*".

- The `m//g` is tricky and I removed it.
- `grep` checks a condition and passes a line through if the condition evaluates true. In such scalar context `/.../g` modifier has effects which are a very different story, removed.
- For the same reason as above, the capturing `()` is unneeded (excessive).
- Cleaning up the syntax helps readability here, removed `m/`.

**Note on regex**

In scalar context `/.../g` modifier does the following, per [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#More-matching):

> successive matches against a string will have //g jump from match to match

The empty string pattern `m//g` also has effects which are far from obvious, stated above.

Taken together these produce non-trivial results in my tests and need mental tracing to understand. I removed them from the code here since leaving them begs a question on whether they are intended trickery or subtle bugs, thus distracting from the actual question -- which they do not affect at all.

Comment: Working with just the first pattern, the OP's version rejects a simple line with 'IIIA' by itself but accepts a compound  line with 'IIIB IIIC'.  Your version and that of @ikegami accept both.  Until the OP weighs in on what the actual input is, how can you say all these other elements aren't necessary?

Comment: @cdlane  I added a comment on why those are left out, thank you for prompting that. I get such involved behavior in my tests that I'd call the code in OP either a bug or ill-advised.  Unless it's play and experimentation, of course.

Answer (score 2):

- I don't know what you think the `g` modifier does, but it makes no sense here.
- I don't know what you think `//` (a match with an empty pattern)  does, but it makes no sense here.
- In list context, `<$fh>` returns all remaining lines in the file. It returns nothing the second time you evaluate it since since you've already reached the end of the file the first time you evaluated it.

Fix:

```
my @lines = <$fh>;
my @values1 = grep { /III[ABC]/ && /.../ } @lines;
my @values2 = grep { /[012]iii/ } @lines;
```

Of course, substitute `...` for what you meant to use there.